# Rails 4 Passing Json To Ember

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ember.js, active-model-serializers

My Json output is not coming the way as expected by [Ember.](http://andycrum.github.io/ember-data-model-maker/)
I am getting the following output:

```
{
   "user":{
       "id":3,
       "email":"user5@user.com"
       "username":"user5"
    },
   "uploads":[{
       "id":5,
       "user_id":3,
       "image_file_name":"image-2.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id":6,
        "user_id":3,
        "image_file_name":"image-4.jpg"
    }]
}
```

What I am missing is in the user section of the json output is the upload_ids: [upload ids separated with commas] like this:

```
"user":{
       "id":3,
       "email":"user5@user.com"
       "username":"user5",
       "upload_ids":[5,6]
},
```

I have the following in the UserSerializer file:

```
attributes :id, :email, :username
has_many :uploads, embed: :ids, key: "uploads", include: true
```

In the users_controller.rb I have the following:

```
@uploads = @user.uploads.all
respond_with(:user=>@user, :uploads=>@uploads)
```

I have active model serializer gem version 0.9.2.

Please if someone can help with this, it will be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your UserSerializer file embed :ids as follows.

[active_model_serializer version 0.8.3](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/tree/v0.8.3#embedding-associations)

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  embed :ids
  attributes :id, :email, :username
  has_many :uploads, key: "uploads", include: true
end
```

Comment: Did that @kiwiupover, even used the specific gem version that you mentioned and still the output does not change. I did stop the server and restart it after making the changes to be sure.